# How can I determine the index in codepage 850 for a char in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, codepages

I have a text file which is encoded with codepage 850. I am reading this file the following way:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(850)))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Now I need for every character in the string `line` in the loop above the zero-based index of that character which it has in codepage 850, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    int indexInCodepage850 = GetIndexInCodepage850(line[i]); // ?
    //...
}
```

Is this possible and how could `int GetIndexInCodepage850(char c)` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Encoding.GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) on the line. CP850 is an 8-bit encoding, so the byte array should have just as many elements as the string had characters, and each element is the value of the character.

Answer (score 3):

Just read the file as bytes, and you have the codepage 850 character codes:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

You don't get it separated into lines, though. The character codes for CR and LF that you need to look for in the data are 13 and 10.

Comment: Good to know this way but I also need the Unicode string, so I want to keep reading the file with the normal StreamReader. parsifals solution is perfect for us.

Comment: @Hulda: You can use the `Encoding.GetString` method to decode the bytes to get the string, instead of first decoding the data, and then encoding it again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to.

You are already specifying the encoding in the streamreader constructor. 
The string returned from reader.ReadLine() will already have been encoding using CP850

Comment: I don't understand. Does a `string` in C# **have** an encoding? I thought a string is always stored as Unicode string, isn't it? I cannot find any method or property on the `string` type which says something about encoding.

Comment: @Hulda: That is correct, a string is always Unicode. If you want the code page 850 character code for a `char` you would need to encode it again.

Comment: internally .net uses utf-16 yes, but Encoding.GetBytes() will only achieve the same as setting the encoding on the streamreader object.